# processing blocks of records in composite primary key order

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using mysql and would like to process a very large table with a primary key of 4 parts in blocks of 10,000 (marshalling data to another system). The database is offline when I am doing the processing so I don't have to worry about any modifications. Say the primary key is (`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`) which are all integers. I first tried using `LIMIT OFFSET` to achieve this like this:

```
SELECT * FROM LargeTable ORDER BY (A, B, C, D) LIMIT 10000 OFFSET 0;
```

Where I increased the offset by 10000 on each call. This seemed to get very slow as it got towards the higher rows in the table. Is it not possible to do this `LIMIT OFFSET` efficiently?

Then I tried a different approach that uses comparison on the composite primary key. I can get the first block like this:

```
SELECT * FROM LargeTable ORDER BY (A, B, C, D) LIMIT 10000;
```

If the last row of that block has `A = a`, `B = b`, `C = c`, and `D = d` then I can get the next block with:

```
SELECT * FROM LargeTable
WHERE
    A > a OR
    (A = a AND B > b) OR
    (A = a AND B = b AND C > c) OR
    (A = a AND B = b AND C = c AND D > d)
ORDER BY (A, B, C, D) LIMIT 10000;
```

And then repeat that for each block. This also seemed to slow down greatly as I got to the higher rows in the table. Is there a better way to do this? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3):

Start processing data from the very start using just plain

```
SELECT *
FROM LargeTable
ORDER BY (A, B, C, D)
```

and fetch rows one by one in your client code. You can fetch 10000 rows in your fetch loop if you want, or add `LIMIT 10000` clause. When you want to stop this block, remember last tuple (A, B, C, D) that was processed, lets call it `(A1, B1, C1, D1)`.

Now, when you want to restart from last point, fetch rows again one by one, but this time use tuple comparison in your WHERE clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM LargeTable
WHERE (A, B, C, D) > (A1, B1, C1, D1)
ORDER BY (A, B, C, D)
```

(you can also add `LIMIT 10000` clause if you don't want to rely on client code exiting fetch loop prematurely).
Key to this solution is that MySQL correctly implements tuple comparison.

**EDIT**: mentioned that optional `LIMIT 10000` can be added.

Comment: Won't `SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY (A, B, C, D)` return all the rows in one result set?  I think you'd want to add `LIMIT 10000` so MySQL doesn't buffer a giant resultset in a temporary table.

Comment: Not if you exit prematurely. But, I mentioned this in my answer as well.

Comment: I really like the tuple comparison, didn't know you could do that.

Comment: @mvp I like the tuple syntax - but it doesn't appear to have made the query any faster from looking at the explain plan. The plan for the query when I do it as a series of 4 OR statements as above said it would be of type range, use the primary key, use 12 bytes of the key, and examine 44456225 rows, using where. The query with the tuple syntax said it would be of type index, use the primary key, use 28 bytes of the key, and examine 99466971 rows, using where. Doesn't the former beat the latter? If I can figure out how to get the explain plan output to format nicely I will paste it here.

Comment: Make sure you have compound index on `(A,B,C,D)` - it should already exist since you said it is primary key, but who knows. Then, try it with `LIMIT 10000` clause. Your plan should say that it is using that index and needs to examine about 10k rows

Comment: @mvp Correct me if I am wrong, but I think with this approach we can miss some data. Let's consider these 3 rows:
(1,1,1,1), 
(1,1,1,2),
(1,1,2,1)
Then after the second row, the condition is D > 1, so we skip the third row (1,1,2,1)

Comment: @Broccoli, you are wrong. tuple comparison considers whole tuple, not just one component.

Comment: @mvp ok, you are actually right. I tested it and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're probably invoking a sequential scan of the table in some way.

Further, you're conditional *SELECT* is not doing what you think it does. It's short circuiting on the first condition *A > a*.

It'll be more efficient if you skip the *ORDER BY* and *LIMIT* and use a statement like:

```
SELECT *
FROM LargeTable
WHERE A = a AND B = b AND C = c;
```

And just iterate through sets of *a*, *b*, and *c*.

Comment: Yes, it's much easier to a subset of composite key than across all of it. Just make sure it's the left part or you'll be doing table scans each time.

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on the context in which you're doing your 'marshalling' operations, but is there a reason why you can't let the unconstrained SELECT run, and have your code do the grouping into blocks of 10,000 items?

In pseudo-code:

```
while (fetch_row succeeds)
{
    add row to marshalled data
    if (10,000 rows marshalled)
    {
        process 10,000 marshalled rows
        set number of marshalled rows to 0
    }
}
if (marshalled rows > 0)
{
    process N marshalled rows
}
```

Comment: I would do this but the Java program that I'm writing likes to give EOFExceptions while attempting to return these result sets as streaming queries. If I could solve that problem then I could use this technique.

Answer (score 0):

Limit with offset needs to throw away rows until it finds the ones you actually want so it gets slow as you have a higher offset.

Here's an idea. Since your database is offline while you do this the data doesn't actually have to be present during the job. Why not move all processed rows to another table while processing them? I'm not sure it will be faster, it depends on how many indexes the table have but you should try it.

```
CREATE TABLE processed AS LargeTable;

SELECT * FROM LargeTable LIMIT 10000;
INSERT INTO processed SELECT * FROM LargeTable LIMIT 10000;
DELETE FROM LargeTable LIMIT 10000;

DELETE TABLE LargeTable;
RENAME TABLE processed TO LargeTable;
```